# node.js + sqlite: Getting Segmentation fault if I run script twice

Tags: node.js, linux, sqlite

Linux/ node version 12.16.1

I'm trying to learn node.js and have a simple script that fails with a Segmentation fault if I run it twice without waiting a long time (1/2 hour?). I'm guessing it's something stupid but have no idea how to fix it. Here's the code:

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

let db = new sqlite3.Database('./qdb.db');

let sql = `SELECT id,
                  quote,
                  attrib,
                  lastShown
            FROM quotes
            ORDER BY lastShown
            limit 5`;

let upd = `UPDATE quotes 
              SET lastShown = strftime('%s','now')  
              WHERE id = ?`;

db.each(sql, (err, row) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
    //  console.log(`${row.quote} ${row.attrib}`);
    db.run(upd, [`${row.id}`], function(err2) {
            if (err2) {
                return console.error(err2.message);         
            }
        } 
    );
});

db.close();
```

The first call updates my timestamp but the 2nd one fails. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
# /var/www/html/nodeQuotes $ node each.js
# /var/www/html/nodeQuotes $ node each.js
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: I kept playing with it and found that most times it failed on the 2nd immediate call of the script but that occasionally it would let me call it twice without failing but would still fail on the 3rd call. It seems to me to be a bug somewhere other than my code. So I'd like to ask if someone would have recommendations on how to accomplish the update in a way other than how it's currently coded. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem in one of my projects. I ended up solving it by using exec instead. Below, you can find my fixes, but it is a little janky.

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

let db = new sqlite3.Database('./qdb.db');

let sql = `SELECT id,
                  quote,
                  attrib,
                  lastShown
            FROM quotes
            ORDER BY lastShown
            limit 5`;

db.each(sql, (err, row) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
    //  console.log(`${row.quote} ${row.attrib}`);
    var id = '' + row.id;
    db.exec(`UPDATE quotes 
              SET lastShown = strftime('%s','now')  
              WHERE id = ${id}`, (err2) => {
            if (err2) {
                return console.error(err2.message);         
            }
        }).close(err3 => {
         if(err3)
         {
               console.error;
         }
      });

});
```